# grouped case_when returns duplicate rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am grouping by an identifier (the identifier may have multiple rows) and then attempting to make a unique row per identifier by using a `group_by` + `summarize` with a `case_when`.  The idea is if there are 2 or more rows then return a single preset value otherwise return the original value.  The problem is that case_when returns duplicate rows with the preset value.  How do I make sure the output is unique?  I could use a `distinct` but my expectation would be that the value is already unique.  ***dplyr v. 1.0.7***

### MWE

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5),
    fav_color = c('red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'black', 'pink')
) 


dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(
        fav_color = case_when(
            n() > 1 ~ 'Multiple Colors',
            n() == 1 ~ fav_color
        )
    )
```

**Returns**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [5]
     id fav_color      
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 Multiple Colors
2     1 Multiple Colors
3     2 red            
4     3 green          
5     4 Multiple Colors
6     4 Multiple Colors
7     5 pink
```

**What I want `ifelse` gives:**

```
dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(
        fav_color = ifelse(n() > 1, 'Multiple Colors', fav_color)
    )
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id fav_color      
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 Multiple Colors
2     2 red            
3     3 green          
4     4 Multiple Colors
5     5 pink
```

**Note**  Using a character output for the final return results in the correct number of rows:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(
        fav_color = case_when(
            n() > 1 ~ 'Multiple Colors',
            n() == 1 ~ 'Single Color'
        )
    )
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id fav_color      
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 Multiple Colors
2     2 Single Color   
3     3 Single Color   
4     4 Multiple Colors
5     5 Single Color
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with `case_when` is that it evaluates all the outputs for all the values even when the condition is not satisfied.

Consider this example -

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
case_when(a > 0 ~ a * 2, 
          a < 0 ~ 'a' * 2)
```

> Error in "a" * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

So in your case `n() == 1 ~ fav_color` is executed for every group. Since the groups which have more than one row will have more than one value of `fav_color` it maintains the number of rows in the output as the original dataframe. The solution is to use a summarising function as @theQi suggested that will always return an output of length 1.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    fav_color1 = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ 'Multiple Colors',
      n() == 1 ~ fav_color[1]
    )
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#     id fav_color1     
#   <dbl> <chr>          
#1     1 Multiple Colors
#2     2 red            
#3     3 green          
#4     4 Multiple Colors
#5     5 pink
```

---

Not relevant to the question but something worth knowing is `fcase` from `data.table` is different. It evaluates the output only when it is needed.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

data.table::fcase(a > 0, a * 2, 
                  a < 0, 'a' * 2)


#[1] 2 4 6 8
```

Answer (score 2):

`case_when` is not designed to deal with this, according to a Tidyverse developer (Github issue [#5730](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5730#issuecomment-777465764)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce your grouped dataset using aggregate functions. Try below using a `max` on the desired output column:

```
dat %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarize(
 fav_color = case_when(
  n() > 1 ~ 'Multiple Colors',
  n() == 1 ~ max(fav_color)
 )
)
```

Comment: edited to be the output you desire.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `summarise` with `if/else`.  Even `ifelse` is not correct as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be same length

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(fav_color = if(n() > 1) "Multiple Colors" else fav_color)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     id fav_color      
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 Multiple Colors
2     2 red            
3     3 green          
4     4 Multiple Colors
5     5 pink
```

---

According to `?case_when`

> case_when() evaluates all RHS expressions, and then constructs its
> result by extracting the selected (via the LHS expressions) parts.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you expand on "ifelse requires all arguments to be the same length"?

Comment: @TylerRinker According to `?ifelse` `If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.`.  Also, `A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no.`

Comment: In your case, "Multiple Colors" is just a single value, which gets recycled to meet the length.  Suppose if you had two values, instead of just one, then the recycling will have a problem